# Subscript out of range when looping through array excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I am trying to split a string in excel and then writing each element of the string into one column of another sheet but i cant seem to finish looping before it gets a subscript out of range error.

```
Sub S1()

Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim rowValue() As String
Dim i As Variant

For i = 2 To 15500
With Worksheets(1)
    Value2 = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
    rowValue = Split(Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")
    rowValue(11) = rowValue(11) & " " & rowValue(12) & " " & rowValue(13)
    arraySize = UBound(rowValue) - LBound(rowValue) + 1
    If arraySize > 3 Then
        For x = 0 To arraySize
            'Place the split values into 1 column each
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, x + 1).Value = rowValue(x)

        Next x
    Else
        'do nothing
    End If
End With
Next i
```

Above is my code, there are about 15500 rows in the first sheet. Everything works fine from rows 1-29 but after that I got the run-time error 9, subscript out of range.

Anyone knows why the loop stops after 29 rows?

Comment: show your complete code including variable declaration. In which line error pops up?

Comment: That kind of depends: we can't see what's on row 29, or any sample data for that matter!

Comment: Updated the code. The error lies with the line -> Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, x + 1).Value = rowValue(x)

Comment: Worksheet 2 is just an empty sheet.

Comment: I think the value in row 29 doesn't have a long string in which you have 13 words separated by space.When the code stops right click on rowValue and click on Add Watch and check how many values are there in array.

Comment: ensure the data before splitting- i thinking that  u may use data splitting option in excel

Answer (score 2):

## Here is your new code:

```
Sub S1()
    Dim i As Integer, arr_Split() As String
    For i = 2 To 15500
        arr_Split = Split(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1), " ")
        Range(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2), Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2 + UBound(arr_Split))) = arr_Split
    Next i
End Sub
```

Try in out in place of the entire sub.  Excel users often do things **the hard way** instead of checking if there are built-in features already created for the same task.

### Some of the problems with your original subroutine:

- You declare `Wb` as a Workbook but do not use it.
- You don't declare `Value2` but you use it.
- You don't declare `arraySize` but you use it.
- You don't declare `x` but you use it.
- You use a `With`/`End With` Statement for no reason (since you don't refer to `.` between `With` and `End With`).
- The `With`/`End With` Statement begins & ends **14,998 times**. (See below.)
- You hard code 11,12,13, which can be a problem unless all original values are 9 `words` long.
- If (for example) your array has 5 items, `arraySize` will calculate as 3.   (If an array has 5 items, they are numbered 0 to 4, and your formula calculates `arraySize` as 4 minus 1.
- Your `If arraysize>3` line will be incorrect due to errors above.
- You're using a Variant (`i`) to count strictly integers.
- The `For`/`Next` loop is using improper values for `x`.
- `If X=0 then Cells(i, x + 1)` is incorrect since it starts writing at column 1 (replacing the source text).
- `Else 'do nothing` is unneeded since `Else` statements are optional.
- Row numbers are hard coded, meaning that you will always process exactly 14,998 rows.
- There is no `End Sub`. (a copy/paste error I assume)
- You're not using `Option Explicit` (which is why you didn't notice undeclared variables).
- There was a couple more things which I am forgetting at the moment.
  Give me a moment to list all the things wrong with your code...  :)

---

**I left out these lines** since (without sample data) it's unclear what they do.  If I knew what they did, I am positive there's a better way to code the (possibly without hard-coded values).

- `rowValue(11) = rowValue(11) & " " & rowValue(12) & " " & rowValue(13)`
- `If arraySize > 3 Then`

Add them back in if needed, but make sure the variables are declared and that there is no way the hard-coded values will cause a problems can cause a problem with any possible data you have or will ever have.

Comment: what happened to `rowValue(11) = rowValue(11) & " " & rowValue(12) & " " & rowValue(13)`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem:

```
For x = 0 To arraySize
```

An array of size 10 (and lower bound=0) has an upper bound of 9, so there would be (eg) no rowValue(10)

Reworked with bounds checking:

```
Sub S1()

    Dim Wb As Workbook, rowValue, i As Long, ub As Long

    For i = 2 To 15500

        rowValue = Split(Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")
        ub = UBound(rowValue)

        If ub >= 13 Then
            rowValue(11) = rowValue(11) & " " & rowValue(12) & " " & rowValue(13)
        End If

        If ub > 2 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, ub + 1).Value = rowValue
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Definitely will cause the error.  Now the big question is ... why doesn't it crash on row 2 ?!?  (Maybe rows 2 to 29 only contain 2 or fewer spaces??)

Comment: No - it can't be less than 3 spaces, or else the line setting position 11 would crash.

Answer (score 0):

use `On Error Resume Next`

```
Sub S1()

    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim rowValue() As String
    Dim i As Variant

    For i = 2 To 15500
        With Worksheets(1)
            Value2 = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
            On Error Resume Next ' USE THIS
            rowValue = Split(Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")
            rowValue(11) = rowValue(11) & " " & rowValue(12) & " " & rowValue(13)
            arraySize = UBound(rowValue) - LBound(rowValue) + 1
            If arraySize > 3 Then
                For x = 0 To arraySize
                    'Place the split values into 1 column each
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, x + 1).Value = rowValue(x)

                Next x
            Else
                'do nothing
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0  ' USE THIS
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It is fine, hiding an anticipated error, when the code itself is not factored well and no naming convention is followed.

Comment: But the error **isn't** anticipated, otherwise the OP wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: "Don't worry about the easily-fixable errors in your code"